# Error building Marmalade

Tags: marmalade

I'm trying to build Marmalade example.

The Marmalade Hub is giving me the following error:

> Current Build: GCC ARM Debug (Not Found)

The Dependency Checker has only one error:

> Android Signing Certificates Not Found

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you did not compile the project as ARM GCC Debug before, but try to build package